# Аналог LIKE в LINQ

Tags: linq

Есть запрос в среде MS-SQL

```
select * from myTable where myTable.field like 'tra%ata'
```

Как это реализовать в LINQ?

Comment: никак, нужно использовать [SqlFunctions - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чистом LINQ надо либо использовать комбинацию `Contains`/`StartsWith`/`EndsWith`, либо регэкспы. В вашем случае можно обойтись таким выражением:

```
Where(i => i.field.StartsWith("tra") && i.field.EndsWith("ata"))
```

Если же вам это нужно в LINQ2SQL, то используйте специализированный метод [`SqlMethods.Like()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like(v=vs.110).aspx) (но работает он **только** в контексте LINQ2SQL):

```
from i in db.myTable
where SqlMethods.Like(i.field, "tra%ata")
select i
```

Comment: а регэкспы разве можно использовать? они будут в sql'ные транслированны?

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Видел реализацию метода SqlMethods.Like() но не понял что подключить нужно в C# для его использования?

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC читайте внимательнее документацию, там все написано: `Assembly:  System.Data.Linq (in System.Data.Linq.dll)`

Comment: Хм, а мне показалось надо linq, который потом в mssql пойдет

Comment: Метод на QSL отрабатывает а на клиенте им пользоваться нельзя. Допустим делаю linq to list<string>. Это получается остается только Where(i => i.field.StartsWith("tra") && i.field.EndsWith("ata"))?